# Ajax success is triggered twice in webkit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, webkit

I can't for the life of me figure why the success function is triggered twice. It's necessary to fire only once because of the following page transition. This problem only appears to have affect in webkit browsers safari/chrome. Firefox works the way it's supposed to. It doesn't fire twice if I take out the line that says removeClass.

```
//Page Loader Variables
var ajaxPageRequest;
var ajaxPageLoading = false;



function getPage(url) {
    //Checks to see if transition is complete before changing pages
    $('.pageContent, .loadbar').addClass('init');
    var newPage = $('#pageContent');
    newPage.one('oTransitionEnd transitionEnd webkitTransitionEnd',
      function(e) {
        if (ajaxPageRequest) {
          ajaxPageRequest.abort();
          ajaxPageRequest = '';
        }
        replacePageContent(url);
      }
    );
  }

function replacePageContent(ajaxPageAddress) {
    if (ajaxPageRequest) {
      ajaxPageRequest.abort();
      ajaxPageRequest = '';
    }
    ajaxPageLoading = true;
    ajaxPageRequest = $.ajax({url: ajaxPageAddress, async: true, cache: false})
      .success(function(ajaxPageData) {
        ajaxPageRequest = '';
        if (ajaxPageLoading) {
          ajaxPageLoading = false;
          console.log('load complete' + ": " + ajaxPageAddress);
          if (ajaxPageData) {
            if (ajaxPageAddress != window.location) {
              //add the new page to the window.history
              window.history.pushState({
                path: ajaxPageAddress
              }, '', ajaxPageAddress);
            }
            $("#pageContent").html($(ajaxPageData).find("#pageContent > *")).removeClass('init');
            $('#pageContent, .loadbar').removeClass('init');
          }
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: how is `replacePageContent` triggered?

Answer (score 0):

The bit about "oTransitionEnd transitionEnd webkitTransitionEnd" causes this to happen by the looks of it as webkit browsers would both support transitionEnd and webkitTransitionEnd causing both events to fire at the same time. I added a little browser support detection and it cleared it all up.